# python tkinter ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a calculator program with Python.
I want to output the sum of the numbers input using tkinter.

```
enter code here
def plus():
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e3.delete(0, END)
    x = int(e1.get()) #Inputed value.
    y = int(e2.get()) #Inputed value.
    return e3.insert(0, x+y)

e1 = Entry(window)
e2 = Entry(window)
e3 = Entry(window)
```

Comment: In your own words, if you remove all of the text from the `e1` entry, and then try to convert the text that's there to an integer, what integer result do you think you should get? Why? In your own words, if you want to remove the text from the entry, and also convert *the text that is currently there* to an integer, then which of those two things should happen first? Why?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and keep in mind that Stack Overflow [should be treated as a last resort, after your best attempt to solve the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). If you get stuck, and have narrowed it down as best you can, you should at least make sure to *ask an actual question*, while explaining what you tried.

Comment: I am not being aggressive at all. I am focusing your attention on the aspects of the code that you need to consider, following the Socratic method. I am also informing you about Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: why is `e3` an `Entry`? from the given code it doesn't seem that it would ever be used by the user, meaning it can simply be a read-only widget, such as `Label`

Answer (score 1):

Why did you do this before you `get()`?

```
e1.delete(0, END)
e2.delete(0, END)
```

They go before `e1.get()` and `e2.get()`, so when you run `e1.get()`, it will return `""`. Then you should swap their order like this:

```
def plus():
    e3.delete(0, END)
    x = int(e1.get())
    y = int(e2.get())
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e2.delete(0, END)
    return e3.insert(0, x+y)

e1 = Entry(window)
e2 = Entry(window)
e3 = Entry(window)
```

This is my answer, thanks.